# "Мы не ценим то(,) что имеем". Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

**Мы не ценим то_что имеем.**

Нужна ли запятая? Мне кажется, что нужна.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Мы не ценим то, что имеем.**

Это СПП, придаточное "что имеем" отделяется запятой.

Пример из Нацкопруса:

> Как иногда **мы не ценим то, что имеем**, и призрачные желания заставляют нас менять свою судьбу. [Сергей Есин. Маркиз Астольф де Кюстин. Почта духов, или Россия в 2007 году. Переложение на отечественный Сергея Есина (2008)]

Answer (score 0):

Да, в этом случае запятая необходима.

Comment: Ответы должны быть аргументированы.